# Multiple UISwitch on the view controller

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have two `UISwitch`, both call the same method on the click event, so in that methodi need to distinguish between the two switch to know who send the event. For that i assigned `tag` only for one of them:

```
switch1.tag=0;
```

In the method that gets fired when one of these `UISwitch` gets clicked, i make that test:

```
-(void)switchValueGetsChanged:(UISwitch*)sender{

    if (sender.tag==0) {
        NSLog(@"It's switch 1");
    }else{

        NSLog(@"It's switch 2");
    }
```

Now, when i run the code, what i noticed is that i get always the first message:

```
    NSLog(@"It's switch 1");
```

Even when i click on the second `UISwitch`. I solved the issue by assigning a tag for the second `UISwitch` as well:

```
switch1.tag=0;
switch2.tag=1;
```

Now, the problem is solved, so my question is: if you get more than one `UISwitch`, and you want to judge on the `tag` value, is it mandatory to assign `tag` property for all your `UISwitch`objects ? Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> if you get more than one `UISwitch`, and you want to judge on the `tag` value, is it mandatory to assign `tag` property for all your `UISwitch` objects?

If you want to differentiate any view based on its `tag` property then yes, you must set its `tag` property. How else could you check the `tag` if you don't set the `tag`?

BTW - don't use `0` as one of your tag values. This is the default for all views so setting it to `0` doesn't really help any.